# AWS Glue dynamic frame creation error - InvalidInputException

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog, aws-lake-formation

I'm trying to create Glue DynamicFrame from S3 object using following command.

```
df = glue_context.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database="s3_bucket_name",
                                                   table_name="s3_object_name")
```

This gives an `InvalidInputException` with reason being `Cannot vend credentials for buckets in multiple regions`

This has worked earlier in a similar setup, but it is failing in the new account I tried. Any clue on what could be wrong here?

Full error

````
com.amazonaws.services.gluejobexecutor.model.InvalidInputException: Cannot vend credentials for buckets in multiple regions (Service: AWSLakeFormation; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidInputException```
````

Comment: would check your aws credentials file, and make sure current IAM roles are set for that user

Comment: Are you trying to read from multiple buckets in different regions?

Comment: @bdcloud - I'm not trying to read from multiple buckets. Its one bucket in "us-east-1" region, thats why I'm confused here.

Comment: @BanjoObayomi - AWS credentials looks fine and IAM roles are set.